# Calling a method from a AMP protocol

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I'm trying to implement a call to a method defined by myself which belongs to a AMP protocol.

I followed the next steps.
On the client side I have started a reactor as follows.

```
connector = reactor.connectSSL('localhost', 1234,\
 ClientReconnectFactory(self.CONNECTION_INFO, gsi),\
  ClientContextFactory())
```

`self.CONNECTION_INFO` holds some useful variables for the connection process.

`gsi` is an variable who calls a class with some methods.

```
gsi = GroundStationInterface(self.CONNECTION_INFO, "Vigo", ClientProtocol)
```

`ClientReconnectFactory` is an object inherited from `ReconnectingClientFactory` with the following code:

```
def __init__(self, CONNECTION_INFO, gsi):
    self.CONNECTION_INFO = CONNECTION_INFO
    self.gsi = gsi
    # self.continueTrying = 0

def startedConnecting(self, connector):
    log.msg('Starting connection...')

def buildProtocol(self, addr):
    log.msg('Building protocol...')
    self.resetDelay()
    return ClientProtocol(self.CONNECTION_INFO, self.gsi)

def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
    self.continueTrying = None

    log.msg('Lost connection. Reason: ', reason)
    ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self,\
     connector, reason)

def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
    self.continueTrying = None

    log.msg('Connection failed. Reason: ', reason)
    ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed(self,\
     connector, reason)
```

`ClientProtocol` is my protocol.

```
class ClientProtocol(AMP):

def __init__(self, CONNECTION_INFO, gsi):
    self.CONNECTION_INFO = CONNECTION_INFO
    self.gsi = gsi

    log.msg('he pasado por el __init_- de ClientProtocol')

def connectionMade(self):
    self.user_login()
    self.gsi.connectProtocol(self)

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    log.err("Connection lost")
    log.err(reason)
    self.gsi.disconnectProtocol()

@inlineCallbacks
def user_login(self):        
    try:
        res = yield self.callRemote(Login,\
         sUsername=self.CONNECTION_INFO['username'],\
          sPassword=self.CONNECTION_INFO['password'])
        log.msg(res)
        res = yield self.callRemote(StartRemote,\
         iSlotId=self.CONNECTION_INFO['slot_id'])
        log.msg(res)
    except Exception as e:
        log.err(e)
        reactor.stop()

def processFrame(self, frame):

    log.msg('Received frame: ' + frame)
    res = yield self.callRemote(SendMsg, sMsg=frame,\
     iTimestamp=misc.get_utc_timestamp())

    log.msg(res)
```

How could I call the function procressframe from the object gsi? 
This object belongs to another module.

I tried to create a call with the decorator @staticmethod but it didn't recognize the method callRemote althoght the object gsi is inhereted from ClientProtocol.

I would appreciate any help.